# Error trying to use Merge Into instead of Update

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to speed up my updates and converting my update / set statement to a merge into / using.

Old Version

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
UPDATE /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ TEST_REPORT_2 rep 
SET    ( title ) = (
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ doctitle.valstr Title 
FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_SHRUNK_V3 doctitle 
WHERE  doctitle.id = rep.dataid 
    AND doctitle.defid = 3072256 
    AND doctitle.attrid = 5 
    AND doctitle.vernum = (SELECT MV.MAX_VERNUM
                                FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS_V1 MV
                                WHERE  MV.id = rep.dataid
                                    AND defid = 3072256 
                                    AND attrid = 5) 
    AND doctitle.defvern = (SELECT MV.MAX_DEFVERN
                                FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS_V1 MV
                                WHERE  MV.id = rep.dataid  
                                    AND defid = 3072256 
                                    AND attrid = 5));
```

New Version

```
MERGE INTO TEST_REPORT_2 REP
USING MV_LLATTRDATA_SHRUNK_V3 doctitle
    ON (REP.DATAID = doctitle.ID
        AND doctitle.defid = 3072256 
        AND doctitle.attrid = 5 
        AND doctitle.vernum = (SELECT MV.MAX_VERNUM
                                FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS_V1 MV
                                WHERE  MV.id = rep.dataid
                                    AND defid = 3072256 
                                    AND attrid = 5) 
        AND doctitle.defvern = (SELECT MV.MAX_DEFVERN
                                FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS_V1 MV
                                WHERE  MV.id = rep.dataid))
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    TITLE = doctitle.VALSTR;
```

However I'm getting an error saying: "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: Regardless of the immediate issue (of making MERGE work) - why do you expect MERGE to be faster than UPDATE? Do test both ways - it would be instructive for all of us if you could post what you find out.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the logic for `defvern` needs to include `defid` and attrid`?

```
    AND doctitle.vernum = (SELECT MV.MAX_VERNUM
                            FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS_V1 MV
                            WHERE  MV.id = rep.dataid
                                AND defid = 3072256 
                                AND attrid = 5) 
    AND doctitle.defvern = (SELECT MV.MAX_DEFVERN
                            FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS_V1 MV
                            WHERE  MV.id = rep.dataid
                                AND defid = 3072256 
                                AND attrid = 5)
```

That is how the logic is structured in the `update`.

Comment: Oh that's a bad copy/paste job and I don't get the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

One of the select statements of this form:

```
some_column = (select x from y where z)
```

is retuning multiple values.

A simple fix is:

```
some_column = (select max(x) from y where z)
```

But one way or another you must force this select to return only one value

Comment: Are you you referring to the subquery related to `AND doctitle.vernum`